# Missing template error in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

`new.html` is a registration form ,which creates tutor account .
It involves error handling . `_error_messages.html.erb` is the file which handles the error ,like should be filling in all text fields .
e.g , showing :
`

```
The form contains 3 errors.

    Name can't be blank
    Password confirmation can't be blank
    Password confirmation doesn't match Password
```

However ,when submits the form without any input in `new.html`  ,it shows the error

> Missing template tutors/register, application/register with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "D:/Sites/abc/app/views"

new.html.erb

```
 <% provide(:title, 'Registeration') %>
    <h1>Tutor Registration</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(@tutor) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>



     <%= f.label :gender %>
                <%= f.select(:gender, ['Male', 'Female'] , class: 'form-control' )%>


          <%= f.label :tutor_education_level %>
                    <%= f.select(:education_level, ['Bachelor', 'Master', 'Doctor'] , class: 'form-control' )%>


          <%= f.label :tutor_institution %>
          <%= f.text_field :institution, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= f.label :tutorial_experience %>
          <%= f.text_field :experience, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= f.label :tutor_preferred_district %>
          <%= f.text_field :district, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :tutor_preferred_subject %>
          <%= f.text_field :subject, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= f.label :tutor_required_student_level %>

           <%= f.select(:student_level, ['P1-P3', 'P4-P6', 'S1-S3', 'S4-S6'] , class: 'form-control' )%>


          <%= f.submit "Create tutor's account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if @tutor.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@tutor.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @tutor.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Tutor -controller

```
 class TutorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_tutor, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_tutor,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @tutors = Tutor.all
  end

  def show
    @tutor = Tutor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @tutor = Tutor.new
  end

  def create
    @tutor = Tutor.new(tutor_params)
    if @tutor.save
      log_in @tutor
      flash[:success] = "Congratulations! Your registration is successful!"
      redirect_to @tutor
    else
      render 'register'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @tutor = Tutor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    if @tutor.update_attributes(tutor_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated successfuly!"
      redirect_to @tutor
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  # Handle sign-up failure, to redirect the tutor to the registeration form again
  def tutor_params
    params.require(:tutor).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :address,:gender ,:education_level,:institution,:exprience,:district,:subject,:student_level)
  end

  def logged_in_tutor
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  def correct_tutor
    @tutor = Tutor.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_tutor?(@tutor) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Show the `tutors` controller with `new` action.

Comment: @Зелёный   `def new
   @tutor = Tutor.new
  end`

Comment: Please _post the full code_ of `tutors` controller _to the question body_.

Comment: @Зелёный updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form, request sends to the `create` action:

```
 def create
    @tutor = Tutor.new(tutor_params)
    if @tutor.save
      # if @tutor valid save it and redirect to show action
      redirect_to @tutor
    else
      # else render the register template(or action)
      render 'register'
    end
  end
```

In the `create` action there is a conditional `if`, in the first case all is good, `@tutor` has been saved and Rails call redirect to show action, otherwise Rails trying to `render` register template which is not exists(the errors claims about it). To resolve that issue create `register` template with desired html code which should run if `@tutor` isn't saved.